# connection reset by peer error when connecting to router using telnet library in python?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04

I am stuck with connection reset by peer error for last 2 weeks.Wat I do in code is...

> ```
> Every 5 mins I connect to router and fetch data form them using telnet library in python.I have 12 routers so used pyhotn threading class . i.e each thread for each router.
> ```

does the python thread causes this connection reset by peer error because no network related problems from routers.or any other reasond???

Any problem in thread due to GIL?

Answer (score 0):

"Connection reset by peer" means that the other end of the connection is requesting the connection termination.

Comment: so no problem in python telnet lib right....its due to network related problem.any possible reasons?

Comment: It could still potentially be something in the python lib - bad negotiation of options, etc. - but that wouldn't be the first thing I'd suspect. Make sure you can connect using other telnet clients first...